# Use Groovy to FTP Latest File

Tags: java, groovy, scripting, ftp

I'm writing a script using Groovy which will connect to an FTP and download the latest file to the local machine to perform additional work on the data.

I'm trying to use FTPClient & FTPFile in order to do this, but not too sure how to go about selecting the latest file?

I've managed to get it to connect to the FTP and return a list of the files so far.

```
//Retrieve latest file from FTP
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient()
ftpClient.connect('xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx')
ftpClient.login("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxx")

FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles()
for (FTPFile file : files) {
    println(file.getName())
}

ftpClient.logout()
ftpClient.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I see You're using Apache Commons Net. You Can sort files by timestamp and just pick the last element of the collection.

```
FTPFile latest = ftpClient.listFiles().sort { it.getTimestamp().getTime() }.first() //handle NoSuchElementException
```

Or:

```
FTPFile latest = ftpClient.listFiles().max { it.getTimestamp().getTime() }
```

More groovier:

```
def latest = ftpClient.listFiles().max { it.timestamp.time }
```